# Retrieving the Com Class Factory error

Tags: .net, vb.net, com

When i opened  the application, it threw following error,

Error in function: Main
  Error message: Retrieving the COM class factory for Component with CLSID {XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXX} failed due to the following error:80040154

Adding more on the above, the application worked in windows xp, but when it is moved to windows 7 , it threw the above error.( i dont have the code with me, this application is in remote location)

Please provide your valuable input on this, what could be reason for this error.

Answer (score 0):

Error 80040154 indicates that the COM class is not registered. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be registered; this is usually handled by the installer for whatever component you are trying to create.

Try using regsvr32.exe to register the COM component (the DLL name is passed on the command line).

Some documentation for regsvr32 is here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx